# Is it possible to integrate a quadratic nonlinear ordinary differential equation?

Tags: calculus

How, if possible, would one integrate the following ODE:

$dx/dt=ax^2+bx+c$,

where $a$, $b$ and $c$ are constants and $x=x(t)$.

Comment: See also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2591781/error-while-integrating-reciprocal-of-irreducible-quadratic-int-frac1ax2) question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's separable:

$$\frac{dx}{ax^2+bx+c} = dt.$$

We know how to integrate every rational expression.
If $ax^2+bx+c$ factors, use partial fractions.  If not, complete the square and do a trig substitution.